How to create working dll assembly for Powershell script, which will work on different computers?
I have code which must load MySQL.Data.dll as MySQL\Connector and System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll so that I can use SQL-transactions
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("D:\MySQL.Data.dll")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("D:\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll")

$server = "192.168.0.80"
$database = "mydb"
$user = "sql"
$password = "mypass1"

$connection = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection
$connection.ConnectionString = "server=$server;database=$database;uid=$user;pwd=$password"

$connection.Open()

$transaction = $connection.BeginTransaction()

try {

    $cmd = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand
    $cmd.Connection = $connection
    $cmd.Transaction = $transaction


    $cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO mytable (column1, column2) VALUES (@value1, @value2)"
    $cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value1", "somevalue1") | Out-Null
    $cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value2", "somevalue2") | Out-Null
    $cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() | Out-Null


    $transaction.Commit()

}
catch {

    if ($transaction -ne $null) {
        $transaction.Rollback()
    }
    Write-Host "Error: $_"
}
finally {

    $connection.Close()
}

The problem is, that I have en eror loading this "unsafe.dll" An error
Exception when calling "BeginTransaction" with "0" arguments: "Could not load file or assembly "System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=4.0.4.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" or one of its dependencies. The specified file could not be found."

indicates, that MySQL.Data.dll trying to load some certain version of this 'unsafe.dll' and can not do this. And it raises an error.
It there any way for me to fix it somehow? Because I need transactions in my Powershell script, and I can not use SimplySQL module because of some issues.

See following code to add an unmanaged dll to powershell : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-type?view=powershell-7.4#example-4-call-native-windows-apis

Thank you @jdweng. Yet I can not find necessary parameters for MySQL.Data.dll and System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll to load them in unmanaged way. Can I obtain these parameters somehow or somewhere? Seems to me that MySQL.Data.dll is compiled with link to certain version of System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll which is 4.0.4.1 And there is no way to fix it from PS Script or other methods, so that MySQL.Data.dll would use current version of "unfase.dll" presented in Windows. I hope I am wrong, though

MySQL.Data.dll is managed.  Here is the source for the Unsafe dll : https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe/4.5.3

the problem is that I need to store dll locally and then distribute on each client together with powershell script. Because some clients can not download it, because there is no internet connection

Ok, it works. The thing is, that you need to load exactly 4.0.4.1 version of System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll because with link to this certian version only any current MySQL.Data.dll is assembled (compiled) and compatible.
I just downloaded System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll version 4.0.4.1 from from NuGet repository, manually. I mean I did not instal it as package, just looked it through via NuGet Package Explorer and double-clicked necessary *.dll to download.
My code with working transactions to MySQL server from Powershell 5.0 script now looks like:
# | Load MySQL Connector from Windows GAC (Global Assembly Cache)
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("MySql.Data")

# | Set path to dll file 
$unsafe_dll_path = "D:\Connectors\from-nuget\net461\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll"

# | Load dll for trancactions
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::UnsafeLoadFrom($unsafe_dll_path)

# | define connection
$connection = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection

# | Create and open connection to MySQL database
$connection = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection
$connection.ConnectionString = "server=192.168.0.80;database=mydatabase;user id=sqldbwriter;password=mypassword"
$connection.Open()

# | Begin transaction
$transaction = $connection.BeginTransaction()

try {
    # | Create command
    $command = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand
    $command.Connection = $connection
    $command.Transaction = $transaction

    # | Execute command in transaction's pipe
    $command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO mytable (column1, column2) VALUES ('value25', 'value26')"
    $command.ExecuteNonQuery()

    # | Commit transaction
    $transaction.Commit()
    Write-Host "Transaction success."
}
catch {
    # | Rollback  transaction incase of errors
    $transaction.Rollback()
    Write-Host "Transaction cancelled."
    throw
}
finally {
    # | Close connection
    $connection.Close()
}

Also, as you can see, it seems there is no need even to download Oracle's MySQL\Connector from their site for it has already been stored in Windows GAC (Global Assembly Cache)
GAC    Version        Location                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
---    -------        --------                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
True   v4.0.30319     C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\MySql.Data\v4.0_8.3.0.0__c5687fc88969c44d\MySql.Data.dll                                                                                                                                        
False  v4.0.30319     D:\Connectors\from-nuget\net461\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll                                                                                                                                                                 
1
Transaction success.

P.S. May be it is also possible now to use 'LoadFrom' method instead of 'UnsafeLoadFrom'. I have not checked yet.
P.P.S. Ironic (c) but Windows GAC has System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll in store, but version 6.0 and incompatible with MySQL.Data.dll from - tadaam! - Windows GAC. Perfect example of dll-hell, if you ask me :-)
